# adding question_id to list of bookmarks in user schema angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

**Schema:**

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    ques_bookmarks: [{ type: String }],
})
```

**Controller:**

```
.controller('questionsController', function(questionsFactory, $routeParams, $scope) {
  var that = this;
  questionid = $routeParams.id;
  stats = false;

  var getallQuestions = function() {
    questionsFactory.getQuestions(function(data) {
      that.questions = data;
      console.log(data)
    })
  }
  getallQuestions();
  this.getthatQuestion = function() {
    questionsFactory.getthatQuestion(questionid, function(data) {
      questionsFactory.checkBookmark(questionid, function(response) {

        if (response == "bookmarked") {
          data.stats = true;
        } else {
          data.stats = false;
        }
      })
      that.question = data;
    })
  }
  this.addbookmark = function(qId) {
    questionid = qId;

    questionsFactory.addBookmark(qId, function(response) {
      that.getthatQuestion();
    })
  }
  this.removebookmark = function(qId) {
    questionid = qId;

    questionsFactory.removeBookmark(qId, function(response) {
      that.getthatQuestion();
    })
  }

  this.checkbookmark = function(question) {
    questionsFactory.checkBookmark(question._id, function(response) {
      if (response == "bookmarked") {
        question.stats = true;
      } else {
        question.stats = false;
      }
    })
  }
});
```

**Factories:**

```
.factory('questionsFactory', function($http, AuthToken, $route) {
  var factory = {};
  var token = AuthToken.getToken();
  var userid = AuthToken.getid();

  factory.getQuestions = function(callback) {
    $http({
      url: 'api/all_questions',
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'x-access-token': token
      }
    }).then(function(response) {
      callback(response.data)
    })
  }

  factory.getthatQuestion = function(info, callback) {
    $http({
      url: 'api/one_question',
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'x-access-token': token
      },
      params: {
        question_id: info
      }
    }).then(function(response) {
      console.log('[FACTORY] one question data:', response.data);
      callback(response.data)
    })
  }

  factory.addBookmark = function(info, callback) {
    $http({
      url: 'api/add_bookmark_ques',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'x-access-token': token
      },
      params: {
        'user_id': userid
      },
      data: {
        'ques_id': info
      }
    }).success(function(data) {
      console.log('add bookmark: ' + data);
      callback()
    })
  }

  factory.checkBookmark = function(info, callback) {
    $http({
      url: 'api/check_bookmark_ques',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'x-access-token': token
      },
      params: {
        'user_id': userid
      },
      data: {
        'ques_id': info
      }
    }).success(function(data) {
      console.log('check bookmark: ' + data);
      callback(data)
    })
  }

  factory.removeBookmark = function(info, callback) {
    $http({
      url: 'api/remove_bookmark_ques',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'x-access-token': token
      },
      params: {
        'user_id': userid
      },
      data: {
        'ques_id': info
      }
    }).success(function(data) {
      console.log('remove bookmark: ' + data);
      callback()
    })
  }
  return factory
})
```

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="questionsController as questCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="question in questCtrl.questions>
        <div ng-init="questCtrl.checkbookmark(question)">
            <div ng-if="question.stats" ng-click="questCtrl.removebookmark(question._id)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></div>
            <div ng-if="!question.stats" ng-click="questCtrl.addbookmark(question._id)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty"></div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I click on the glyphicon to add/remove it to the list of bookmarks, the database successfully updates but the icon doesn't change. it only changes when the page is refreshed.

How to resolve this?

Comment: @developer033 any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you change your bookmarks in database you dont actually changing the value on client side, just on the server side.
the below codes doesn't do anything for that :

```
   this.addbookmark = function(qId){
    questionid = qId;

    questionsFactory.addBookmark(qId, function(response){
        that.getthatQuestion();
    })
}
this.removebookmark = function(qId){
    questionid = qId;

    questionsFactory.removeBookmark(qId, function(response){
        that.getthatQuestion();
    })
}
```

and the method here actually returns another javascript object instance(named data that overrides the bound that.question) that is not bound to view so changing it will not effect your view:

```
  // the problem is that
    this.getthatQuestion = function(){
        // when you call two asynchronus functions
        questionsFactory.getthatQuestion(questionid, function(data){
            //first one returns result and you gave value already to the angular
            questionsFactory.checkBookmark(questionid, function(response){
            // second one return later and you havent told angular about this response
            if(response == "bookmarked"){
                data.stats = true;  
            }
            else{
                data.stats = false;  
            }
             // with the each function below we find view-bound object and change its property so angular will know about this change.
             angular.forEach(that.questions,function(e){
                if(e._id == questionid)
                    e.stats = data.stats; 
             });
        })
        })
    }
```

Ps :  I think you need to try better naming conventions / casing as i could understand what your code does at 4th read and also you have misunderstood what factories does and what services does.

Comment: getAllQuestions method has something like   that.questions = data;
checkbookmark callback is like :   that.question = data;

Is this a mistype or i didn't catch something?

Comment: getAllQuestions sets questions array whereas checkbookmark is for one question inside that array

Comment: so that that.question is different as i understood. If this is the case you didnt find the question reference same as i mentioned on my reply you can try    :  for(var i in that.questions) {   if(that.questions[i]._id == that.questionid) {  that.questions[i].stats = data.stats;  } }

Comment: it still won't change instantly, the icon changes only on page refresh... :(

Comment: does it go to same method or method changes amond add and remove without refreshing page?

Comment: sorry, couldn't get you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116414/discussion-between-utsav-bhagat-and-volkan-seckin-akbayir).

Comment: ng-click="questCtrl.removebookmark(question._id)" and ng-click="questCtrl.addbookmark(question._id)"    there is two different actions when hearts changed. When you click twice is it going same method two times or not?

Comment: could you help me with a new question please? ---> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38215147/add-like-dislike-to-answer-which-is-an-objectid-to-a-questionschema